# Throwing object to a specific point in space using touch

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d-games

I am trying to create a little game where I can select a position on my screen(within a panel area) using touch(Touch.position, etc.). Once I have this touch, I am trying to throw an object from a stationary position to the current touch location. I am having trouble being able to convert my touch.position into a Transform from which I can target the object to be thrown. My code hasn't worked for me thus far. I am more than likely suffering from an issue with not knowing what I don't know. Thank you for your time.

```
public int[] distanceToThrow;
public int[] objectToThrow;
public GameObject object;
public Transform throwOrigin;
public float throwingAngle;
public float gravity;
public Transform throwPointPos;
public Transform throwDestination;
public float flightSpeed;

void Update()
{
    if (throwTimer > 0)
    {
        throwTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
        Debug.Log("Timer at: " + throwTimer);
        // Using a single touch as control - Letholor
        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
            Vector3 touchPos = new Vector3(touch.position.x, touch.position.y, 0);
            Debug.Log("You are touching at position: " + touchPos);
            Ray ray = theCamera.ScreenPointToRay(touchPos);
            RaycastHit hitResult;
            Physics.Raycast(ray, out hitResult);
            Vector3 throwDestination = hitResult.point;
            Debug.Log("Throw destination is " + throwDestination);
            Throw();
        }
    }
}

public void Throw() {

    if (throwTimer > 0)
    {
        Debug.Log("Cooling down.");
        return;
    }

    throwTimer = throwResetTimer;

    Debug.Log("Throwing to " + throwDestination);
    Instantiate(object, throwOrigin.position, throwOrigin.rotation);
        }
```

Comment: code! What do have you attempted/where is the problem?

Comment: I have tried using different Touch methods from the Unity documentation and then just changing the variables to suit my needs and I have tried looking up tutorials that may provide some insight into what I'm not understanding, so that I may do research and figure it out. I am coming up short on making my touch into an actual position with which I can target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Touch.position is a screen position. You need to convert it into a world position in order to determine the target coordinates. Here's my suggestion:

---

Step 1: Use **Camera.ScreenPointToRay** to get a world-coordinate ray.

```
Vector3 touchPos = new Vector3 (touch.position.x, touch.position.y, 0);
Ray ray = Camera.ScreenPointToRay(touchPos);
```

You can imagine this being like a "laser sight" from the camera to the touched position.

Step 2: Use **Physics.Raycast** to cast the ray and get the target coordinates.

```
RaycastHit hitResult;
Physics.Raycast(ray, out hitResult);
```

Note that this will only work if the player touches a physics collider. If you want the player to be able to throw the ball at "empty space", you will need to create some invisible walls (that obviously should be set to not collide with the ball) so the raycast has something to hit. Preferably, place the invisible wall at or near your intended maximum throwing range for the player, and parent it to the camera so that you get predictable behaviour.

Step 3: hitResult now has your target position!

```
Vector3 targetLocation = hitResult.point;
```

---

There's another problem with your code, though. Currently, it will fire one bomb every Update as long as the player keeps their finger on the screen. That's a lotta bombs. There are multiple ways to fix this, but I suggest a simple cooldown timer:

```
float maxCooldown = 1f;
float cooldownTimer = 0f;

void Update()
{
    if (cooldownTimer > 0) cooldownTimer -= Time.deltaTime;  
    [the rest of your update code goes here]
}

public void Throw()
{
    //silently return without throwing, if the cooldown has not expired
    if (cooldownTimer > 0)
        return; 

    //safe to throw - set cooldown to max
    cooldownTimer = maxCooldown;

    [the rest of your throw code goes here]
}
```

Hope that helps!

Edit: After looking at your new code, a few things need fixing.

1. You want to decrement the timer when throwTimer > 0, and process the touch when throwTimer <= 0. So keep the decrement instruction where it is, and put the rest of the Update() code either OUTSIDE the **if** statement, or in an **else** block. It won't work otherwise.
2. My mistake: Camera.ScreenPointToRay is not a static method, so you should be using Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay.
3. throwDestination should be a Vector3, but you've declared it wrongly as a Transform at the start of the program, and redeclared it as a Vector3 in Update(). To fix this, you have two options:

   a. Declare ThrowDestination as a Vector3, not a Transform, at the start of your program, and don't re-declare it.

   b. Declare ThrowDestination as a local variable, don't declare it at the start of your script, and pass it directly to Throw() as an argument. This is what I've done in the code below.
4. I believe "object" is a reserved word; you can't call your projectile "object". Call it bomb, or projectile, or something else. In the sample code I'm calling it "projectile".
5. You've instantiated the object in Throw(), but it doesn't have a velocity and doesn't know its destination. We can fix this later; for now, you probably want to make sure the Debug.Log shows you a reasonable position for your throw destination.

```
void Update()
{
    if (throwTimer > 0)
    {
        throwTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
        Debug.Log("Timer at: " + throwTimer);
    }
    // Using a single touch as control - Letholor
    else if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
        Vector3 touchPos = new Vector3(touch.position.x, touch.position.y, 0);
        Debug.Log("You are touching at position: " + touchPos);
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(touchPos);
        RaycastHit hitResult;
        Physics.Raycast(ray, out hitResult);
        Vector3 throwDestination = hitResult.point;
        Debug.Log("Throw destination is " + throwDestination);
        Throw(throwDestination);
    }
}


public void Throw(Vector3 throwDestination) {
    if (throwTimer > 0)
    {
        Debug.Log("Cooling down.");
        return;
    }
    throwTimer = throwResetTimer;
    Debug.Log("Throwing to " + throwDestination);
    Instantiate(projectile, throwOrigin.position, throwOrigin.rotation);
}
```

Here's the updated code. Hope it helps.

Comment: I still can't seem to get it to work. I'm not even getting my debug statements to print out. I'm sorry to be such a bother but can you give it another look please?

Comment: void Update()
    {
        if (throwTimer > 0)
        {
            throwTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
            Debug.Log("Timer at: " + throwTimer);
            // Using a single touch as control - Letholor
            if (Input.touchCount > 0)
            {

Comment: if (Input.touchCount > 0)
            {
                Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
                Vector3 touchPos = new Vector3(touch.position.x, touch.position.y, 0);
               Debug.Log("Tou are touching at position: " + touchPos);
               Ray ray = theCamera.ScreenPointToRay(touchPos);
               RaycastHit hitResult;
               Physics.Raycast(ray, out hitResult);
                Vector3 throwDestination = hitResult.point;
                Debug.Log("Throw destination is " + throwDestination);
                Throw();
            }
        }
    }

Comment: Would it be okay for you to edit your question with the new code?
 It's a bit hard to read in the comments.

Comment: Okay. Few things need fixing here. (oops, sorry, hit Enter too early). Ehh, I'll put it in my answer so it's easier to read.

Comment: It appears that I have a lot more to learn with Unity programming.

Comment: That helped me fix up a bit of the problems that I was having. I had the controller for the bomb in another script. The only thing that's happening now is that it's telling me where I place my finger accurately, but it doesn't carry that information into the Vector3 coordinates for the destination.

Comment: You are touching at position: (651.2, 228.9, 0.0)
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
PlayerController:Update() (at Assets/Scripts/PlayerController.cs:38)
Throw destination is (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
PlayerController:Update() (at Assets/Scripts/PlayerController.cs:43)
Throwing bomb to (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)

Comment: Hi. The script relies on having a physical object (with a Collider) for you to touch. Do you have a "ground" object in the scene, for instance, and are you touching that object?

Comment: Yes. There is a ground in the scene and it has a Box Collider 2D on it. I'm getting the same result. I just tested it out and I will get the response of the coordinates if I add a Box Collider to the object.

Comment: Oh wait... Now that I think about it, is your game a 2D or 3D game?

Comment: It's a 2D game. Does that make a difference in the performance of it all?

Comment: Not really, but it does make things a lot simpler for us. 

In that case, don't add "normal" BoxColliders to the objects. What you need to do is to add a single Quad. Scale and rotate it so it lines up exactly with your 2D playing field, and make sure it does NOT have a 2D collider attached. The stock Quad comes with a 3D MeshCollider, which is what we will use. This Quad will be used specifically for checking your player's touch positions.  (Once you have gotten it working, you can turn off the renderer on the Quad to make it invisible.)

Comment: That just added something beyond my comprehension to the equation. I have added the Quad and I read the Unity documentation on. I know how it's created and how the points are assigned and created, yet, I do not know how it assists me in controlling touch. Also, when I touch the Quad, or anything else for that matter, I still get the same result in my log as I did per my comment on June 1 @ 10:50. The only time I achieved the result of getting my touch is when I changed the code.

Comment: Physics.Raycast(ray, out hitResult);
Vector3 throwDestination = hitResult.point;                                                       
                                                                                                            
   was changed to                                                                        
                                                                                 
Physics.Raycast(ray, out hitResult);
Vector3 throwDestination = touchPos;

Comment: Hmm. The original code was made for a 3D game, but it should work for 2D too, unless the orthographic camera doesn't support Physics.Raycast. At this point you have two options, I guess: (1) drop the raycast and just directly convert the touch position, as per your current code, or (2) try to make the quad work. Without knowing what your camera and scene setup is like, it's a bit hard to recommend which one you should go for. In general, if you've got a "2.5D" setup where you use a perspective camera which might be tilted, then use method 2, else method 1 might work better.